# Ubuntu Import Error: No module named ---- despite having been installed. Could there be a user permission issue or similar

Tags: python, ubuntu, importerror

I am trying to import lxml, html2text, oursql etc.However despite having pip installed all of these I see an error log that looks like this. I feel there could be some permission issues or something fundamental I don't understand. I am using python 2.7 with ubuntu 16.04. I am using pycharm as the IDE to run the scripts.

```
/home/Desktop/SOURCE_CODE/venv/bin/python
/home//Desktop/SOURCE_CODE/notice_parser/parse_mails
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/Desktop/SOURCE_CODE/notice_parser/parse_mails", line 8, in <module>
from modules.config import log
File "/home/Desktop/SOURCE_CODE/notice_parser/modules/config.py", line 5, in <module>
import lxml
ImportError: No module named lxml
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably permissions issue. 
Try running `pip install --user [package]`

Answer (score 0):

By running `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev` it should solve your problem
for more information : https://lxml.de/installation.html

Best regards